# Se prisão e cárcere são sinônimos, por que carcereiro e prisioneiro não significam a mesma coisa?

Tags: etimologia

Perguntinha simples, que tenho certeza que a etimologia será capaz de explicar:

Os vocábulos *[prisão](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/pris%C3%A3o)* e *[cárcere](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/c%C3%A1rcere)* são [sinônimos](http://www.sinonimos.com.br/prisao/), mas por que os substantivos deles derivados, [prisioneiro](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/prisioneiro) e [carcereiro](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/carcereiro) não o são? Até pode-se dizer que são antagonistas!

Comment: Olhando na lista de sinônimos seria engraçado fazer algumas palavras como "celeiro", "ferreiro" e "xadrezeiro" e tentar ver a relação entre elas.

Comment: O meu dicionário diz que que as origens são do latim _carcerarius_ e do castelhano _prisionero_, o que se limita a chutar a pergunta um pouco mais para trás.

Comment: Se açougue e casa de carnes são sinônimos, por que açougueiro e carneiro não são? ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A resposta curta é que o par *cárcere-carcereiro* é típico na língua portuguesa; *prisão-prisioneiro* é atípico e possivelmente caso único. Mas vamos à etimologia das palavras.

### Cárcere e Carcereiro

Segundo o dicionário Houaiss (Lisboa, 2002) *cárcere* e *carcereiro* vêm já do latim. *Cárcere* vem de *carcer*, que já significava “‘prisão, calabouço, masmorra’”, mas também (ver verbete *carcer-*) “‘barreiras que formam a pista por onde devem seguir os carros, bigas, quadrigas; recinto de onde partem os carros numa corrida’”. *Carcereiro* vem do latim tardio *carcerarĭus*, que significava ‘relativo ao cárcere’, donde vem a palavra portuguesa *carcerário*, e também ‘o guarda da prisão, carcereiro’.

O uso do sufixo *-eiro* para exprimir a relação semântica entre *carcereiro* e *cárcere* é comum no português. Segundo o Houaiss (verbete *-eiro*) o sufixo *-eiro* vem do sufixos latinos *ārĭus* e *-arĭus* e, passo a citar, desenvolvendo as abreviaturas,

> […] quanto às noções semânticas, o sufixo ocorre: **1)** predominantemente em vocábulos qualificativos e/ou designativos de homens e mulheres que exercem determinados ofícios, profissões, atividades, etc., os quais são formados por: […] e) substantivo indicativo de local, estabelecimento ou exploração (de mina, de comércio, etc.) + *-eiro/-eira*, formando designativos daqueles que trabalham em tais locais: *açougueiro, adegueiro, banqueiro, fazendeiro, hoteleiro, mineiro ‘trabalhador de mina’, taberneiro, vendeiro*, etc.

### Prisão e Prisioneiro

*Prisão* (Houaiss) vem também do latim “*prehensĭo*, radical de *prehensum*, supino de *prehendĕre*”, verbo que originou o português *prender*. No verbete *prend-*, o Houaiss esclarece que *pre(he)nsĭo* significava “‘direito de prender alguém’ (que assiste a alguns magistrados), donde o sentido concreto de ‘prisão’ em romance”. *Prisioneiro*, segundo o Houaiss, formou-se já no português “provavelmente por influência do francês *prisonnier*”.

A comparação de *prisão prisioneiro* com *cárcere-carcereiro* não é inteiramente justa, porque *prisioneiro* pode ter derivado de *prisão* não no sentido de ‘cárcere’ mas de ‘ato de prender’ ou ‘estado de quem está preso’, sentidos estes que estão mais próximos do sentido original do latim *pre(he)nsĭo e que por isso poderão ter surgido mais cedo. No francês, relevante porque poderá ter influenciado o português, de acordo com o [Centre Nationell de Ressources Textuelles et Lexicales (CNTRL)](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/prisonnier), *prisonnier* está atestado em 1176-81, um pouco mais cedo que [*prison* (CNTRL)](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/prison) no sentido de ‘lugar de detenção’, 1210; o sentido ‘captura’ de *prison* estava já atestado por volta de 1100. Mas as diferenças são pequenas para serem conclusivas.

Mas independentemente da aceção de *prisão* que tenha originado *prisioneiro*, não encontro entre as dezassete noções semânticas de *-eiro* apresentadas no Houaiss (cada uma com várias alíneas) nenhuma que enquadre a relação entre *prisão* e *prisioneiro*. E na verdade, o substantivo que designa alguém sujeito a uma ação ou estado derivados de um verbo (como *prisão* de *prender*) é normalmente o particípio passado do verbo. Por exemplo, *espoliar, espoliação, o espoliado; condenar, condenação, o condenado, excomungar, excomunhão, o excomungado; ferir, ferimento, o ferido*; e na verdade nós temos *prender, prisão, o preso*. *Preso* vem do latim *prehesus* ou *prensus* que é o particípio passado de *prehendĕre* (Houaiss).

Procurando pares com relações semânticas parecidas, ainda pensei em *passagem-passageiro:* o passageiro é alguém que é sujeito a passagem, ainda que voluntariamente, ao contrário do prisioneiro relativamente a prisão. Mas nas primeiras ocorrências que encontrei no [Corpus do Português](https://www.corpusdoportugues.org/hist-gen/2008/), *passageiro* era alguém que passava pelo seu próprio pé, tento portanto a mesma relação de agência relativamente a passagem que caminheiro tem em relação a *caminho*. Portanto parece-me que o par *prisão-prisioneiro* é provavelmente caso único na língua portuguesa

Answer (score 4):

Uma resposta simples seria que cárcere é um *objeto*, enquanto que prisão é um *lugar*, o que induz à acepção do sufixo (que é apenas um indicador de relação) em um termo emprestando o sentido de agente, e em outro o de pertencente.

Outros exemplos desse segundo caso são os gentílicos (brasileiro, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

A língua é convencional, e o uso de sufixos é convencional também.

Veja só:

> marmelada - doce feito de marmelo
>
> limonada - suco de limão
>
> martelada - golpe dado com martelo
>
> palhaçada - ação ou comportamento típico de palhaço

ou seja, o sufixo "ada" pode ter diferentes significados ou funções, dependendo de a qual substantivo ele se liga (e nem sempre há lógica nisso; goiabada é coisa de comer, mas laranjada é para beber, embora tanto laranja quanto goiaba sejam frutas).

"-Eiro" é geralmente um sufixo que carrega a noção "quem faz":

> Padeiro - quem faz pão
>
> Sapateiro - quem faz sapatos
>
> Coveiro - quem faz covas

Daí parece ter adquirido um sentido profissional, que nem sempre tem a ver com a atividade de fazer (o substantivo a que -eiro se liga):

> Banqueiro - quem é dono do banco
>
> Barqueiro - quem "dirige" o barco
>
> Açougueiro - quem trabalha num açougue
>
> Carcereiro - quem cuida do cárcere
>
> Palheiro - quem trabalha com palha

E não quem faz bancos, barcos, açougues, cárceres, ou palha.

Ou seja, o uso do sufixo -eiro é extremamente irregular, como aliás o da maioria dos sufixos. Então a resposta genérica para a sua pergunta é a seguinte: *por que não há nenhuma regra fixa que estabeleça qual a relação entre um substantivo "x" e um substantivo "x+eiro"*. O exemplo é chamativo porque "cárcere" e "prisão" são praticamente sinônimos, enquanto "carcereiro" e "prisioneiro" são complementares. Mas a semelhança de significado entre dois substantivos não implica a semelhança de significado entre as palavras derivadas desses substantivos pela justaposição de um mesmo sufixo.